# Bootstrap 3: vertically centered buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to **vertically center a group of buttons** in a column (see image). The height of the row is dynamic. I've tried a lot of things that I found, but nothing works.

Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ztogupb46o1rfym/bootstrap.PNG

```
<div class="row question even">
    <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-9 text r-text">
        <div>
            dynamic content
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3 r-answer" id="radio">
        <input class="answerradio" id="question3" name="question3" type="hidden" value="4">

        <div class="btn-group" data-target="question3" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button" type="button" value="1">1</button> <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button" type="button" value="2">2</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button" type="button" value="3">3</button> <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button" type="button" value="4">4</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button" type="button" value="5">5</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the my entire code: http://bootply.com/95760

Have some one an idea?

I'm using Bootstrap 3.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Divs are not tables. The button div does not scale with the text one.

Comment: Maybe you should write a little more about what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.question{
    position: relative;
}
.r-answer{
    position: static;
}
.r-answer .btn-group{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -17px;
}
```

Aslong as the buttons stays the same in size this will get them to align center, otherwise you will need javascript to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It works fine! The buttons' size stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late but try using the button-group-vertical class instead of button-group:

```
    <div class="btn-group-vertical" data-target="question3" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button" type="button" value="1">1</button> <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button" type="button" value="2">2</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button" type="button" value="3">3</button> <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button" type="button" value="4">4</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button" type="button" value="5">5</button>
    </div>
```

[Here](http://www.bootply.com/RJYcWAKd1e) is the modified code